# VLC and m3u8 file

Tags: vlc-media-player

Good morning, I created I am testing HLS streaming and I created a simple playlist and segment of a video using the command `ffmpeg -i C:\Users\funny\Desktop\uscita\out.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -g 24 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod -vsync 1 index1.m3u8`.

The source video opens with no problems and ffmpeg encodes it with no problems into index1, that is the playlist file, and index10 index11 index12 being the 3 .ts (video is only 26 secs long).
I installed VLC cause I know it opens playlist files, so I could test my .m3u8, but when I open it with VLC, program starts running but it doesn't play anything. For reference here it is the playlist too :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:11.500000,
index10.ts
#EXTINF:12.000000,
index11.ts
#EXTINF:2.500000,
index12.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Try playback with `ffplay`.

Comment: which input url should I put into ffplay command? can I input the .m3u8 file directly?

Comment: @VincentBavaro: Yes, you can. Incidentally, why not just try it before asking?

Comment: done. it shows me the video without problems. Thanks. Any clue how it doesn't play with vlc tho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr: This looks like a bug with VLC. Use a different player.**

I can reproduce this problem with a set of HLS video file, created by `ffmpeg` as indicated in the question. That is with ffmpeg 4.0.2 and VLC 3.0.4

Symptoms:

Opening the `.m3u8` file with VLC, I get the error message:

> adaptive demux error: Failed to create demuxer (nil) TLS

The debug logs indicate that VLC actually successfully reads the playlist, and finds the TS files, but then something goes wrong.

However, I can successfully play the files with both `ffplay` and [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/), so it looks like the fault is with VLC.

The VLC bugtracker has some similar-looking bug reports, but most are quite old and supposedly fixed.  I did manage to play an HLS stream over HTTP, by opening the URL of the `.m3u8` file, so the bug seems to only apply to downloaded HLS streams. Maybe playing of locally downloaded `.m3u8` files is not a high priority for VLC, so just use a different player.

Comment: Okay. Actually with a closer look after vlc opens it, I can briefly see the video duration blinking to 26 secs before it goes back to 0, so I supposed as well that my vlc was able to read the files anyways. I will also try to upload the stream using an apache webserver and seeeing if vlc will do the same problem with the url.

Comment: I am just confirming that VLC will play the m3u8 content over HTTP but error out with the op message over HTTPS - exact same backend that was delivering the m3u8 content

Answer (score 3):

VLC can't seem to process a m3u8 file with those 'EXT-X' directives in it. Presumably this is a VLC bug (as noted elsewhere) which has yet to be resolved even upto today.

Your best choices are:

1. Edit the `.m3u8` file and delete the EXT-X lines (but do keep those EXTINF lines). You should then be able to play the playlist with VLC, or
2. Use a different application to play the `.m3u8` file as is. `ffplay` is one that will play it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still needs some information on it.

Check "content-type" header of your mpegts chunk. It should be "video/mp2t".